# Let $X$ be the size of $A$. How $X$ is distributed?

Tags: probability

> Let $S$ be a set of $n$ numbers. $A \subseteq S $.
>   Let $X$ be the size of $A$. How $X$ is distributed?

My solution:

Due to the description of $X$, I conclude that $\Omega=\{0,1,2,..,n\}$.

Then $P(X=k)=\frac{1}{n+1}$.

I saw that the correct answer is $\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{2^n}$ but I don't understand why.

More precisely, how do I know to correctly understand what is $\Omega$?

Comment: What are $A$ and $B$?  Are they subsets of $S$?

Comment: The question makes no sense for now, you can't compute a distribution out of nothing, there has to be a distribution given. And $A$ and $B$ are undefined.

Comment: I had a typo. There is no $B$. $A \subseteq S$.

Comment: There are in fact $2^n$ subsets of a set of size $n$.  Of these, ${n \choose k}$ subsets have $k$ elements

Comment: $\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{2^n}$ can be interpreted as follows:  $\binom{n}{k}$ is the number of ways to make a subset of $k$ elements from a set of $n$ elements.  The $2^n$ is the total number of subsets on a set of $n$ elements.  This ratio gives the probability of $X = k$.

Comment: You need to stipulate that each element of $S$ is selected for $A$ with probability $1/2$, or equivalently that all subsets (including the empty set and $S$ itself) are equally likely to be selected as $A$.

Comment: But $X$ is defined as the size of a set and by it's content so why you care about all the possible subset of $S$?

Comment: ask yourself, what is $^nC_k$ and $2^n$, what do they mean from a combinatorial stand point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume that each subset is equally likely to occur (which is not given, hence the question is ill-defined as it is) then there are more subsets of size, say, $2$, than there are subsets of size $n$ (unless $n\leq 2$). You see that $X$ is not uniformly distributed.

The number of subsets of size $k$ is $n\choose k$, and the total number of subsets is $2^n$, hence your formula. This uses the fact that in case of equally likely outcomes, the probability of an event $E$ is given by $$P(E)=\frac{\sharp E}{\sharp \Omega}$$